# Can I reset the "sign in with apple" stable id for a site?

Tags: apple-id

I would like to reset the stable id for a site on which I used "sign in with apple" so that a new account is created and the old one is detached from my apple id. Is this possible? I used "hide my email", but even if I deactivate the generated email address it is just re-appears if I login on the site again.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what “reset the state” means here? Are you [developing apps using Apple API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js) or just someone using iCloud with a specific web browser, specific iOS device and app or Mac app?

Comment: I have used “sign in with apple” on a site and would now like to create a new account on that same site using “sign in with apple”. I cannot delete the old account on the site. Can I delete the connection to my Apple ID somehow so that I can create a new account on the same site using “sign in with apple”?